# How to do background work(like worker role) in web role(IIS)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr, azure-web-roles, azureservicebus

I am working on azure MVC4 application, i need to read messages from servicebus then update online users through IIS(by SignalR). I want to run some worker role type of process within the web role. Looking for best practices to deal with servicebus in web role itself.

Answer (score 0):

To run the "worker role" inside the Web Role, you just need to implement RoleEntryPoint in your Web Project, just like you do in your Worker roles.

Just remember that this "background" process (WaIISHost.exe) runs in total isolation than your Web Application process (w3wp.exe). Although [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/12/02/new-full-iis-capabilities-differences-from-hosted-web-core.aspx) is very old, it still represents very clearly what process do run in your Web Roles.

You could host your SignalR in the "worker role", not the IIS. And pass messages from the web worker to the service bus, and read them from the worker process.

Comment: Hi,
SignalR connectionIds of Users, Groups are available with IIS. SignalR works with IIS only as per signalR team. So i need to read servicebus within the web role itself. please suggest some alternate ways. messages are passing to servicebus from multiple sources.

Comment: You have some delusion. Check the [SignalR SelfHosting](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Self-host) topic. Also there is nothing explicitly mentioned in [Managing Hubs section](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs) that would lead to the conclusion that ConnectionIds and Groups are only available in IIS, or that SignalR itself only runs in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution is to work with a worker role with Service Bus, you can try the worker role with service bus queue.

you can get the required message from the web, send it through the service bus queue to the worker role, and then do the required process.

After that you can send the result back to the webrole whether by using the queue or the service queue backward.

you can check this link, I think he is doing something a little bit similar http://middlewareinthecloud.com/2012/06/23/azureservice-bus-queues-in-worker-roles/

and this is the MSDN URL for the Worker Role With Service Bus Queue
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj149831.aspx